# Entropy calculation

Tags: probability, random-variables, entropy

Let's say we have an unknown random variable whose entropy is $1.75$
Our job is to find minimum distributions for this random variable.

What I wrote was:
$$ p_1 \log_2\Big(\frac 1 {p_1}\Big) + \ldots + p_n \log_2\Big(\dfrac 1 p_n \Big)= \log_2\Bigg[\Big(\frac{1}{p_1}\Big)^{p_1} \cdot \Big(\frac{1}{p_2}\Big)^{p_2} ...\Big(\frac{1}{p_n}\Big)^{p_n}\Bigg]= 1.75$$

So $2^{1.75} = \Big(\dfrac 1 p_1\Big)^{p_1} \cdot \Big(\dfrac 1 p_2\Big)^{p_2} \cdot \ldots \cdot \Big(\dfrac 1 p_n\Big)^{p_n}$ which by using AM-GM, can be found that 
$n \ge 2^{1.75} \implies n = 4$ as min value.

However, finding these probability distribution is proving to be quite tricky.

Any suggestions?

Comment: By "min distributions" do you mean a discrete distribution with the minimum number of states that results in an entropy of $1.75$ bits?  Please be more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a four state system, if all probabilities are equal the entropy is $2$ bits.  If $p_1=1,$ and the others are all zero the entropy is $0$.  by continuity, there must be a value $p$ such that $p_1=1-3p,p_2=p_3=p_4=p$  that has an entropy of $1.75$.  You can find it numerically, if nothing else.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20-1.75=3%2ax%2alog%282,x%29%2b%281-3x%29%2alog%282,1-3x%29) finds two solutions.  Of course, other distributions are possible.

Comment: i actually got it after writing this and leaving for class :) thanks anyhow

Answer (score 0):

One example would be taking the first two probabilities equal with 1/4 and then the other two equal with 1/8! It's exactly 2^1.75

Comment: The sum of the probabilities must equal $1$...

Comment: Changing (only) the first probability to 1/2 happens to work.